# Volumes by Cylindrical Shells - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

I am trying to solve this exercise from a textbook:

$y = x^4, y = 0, x = 1;$ rotated about $x=2$

This is my attempt at solving the problem:

Shell radius: $2 - x$

Shell height: $x^4$

$a = 1$

$b = 2$

$\int_1^2 2π(2-x)x^4dx$

$= 2π(2x^5/5 - x^6/6)_1^2$

$= 2π(2*2^5/5 - 2^6/6 - 2/5 + 1/6)_1^2$

$= 2π(19/10)$

$= 19π/5$

However, the answer is supposed to be 7π/15 according to the solutions manual. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Draw a picture. It will show we need to integrate from $0$ to $1$.

Comment: Oh I see my mistake, and reached the right answer with the new limits.